# listings lstdefinestyle not work with custom defined command

Tags: listings, key-value

I defined a new command named '\showLineNo', and used in '\lstdefinestyle', got an error:

> Package Listings Error: Numbers none unknown. \lstset{style=customstyleone}

sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{listings}

\def\showLineNo{none}

\lstdefinestyle{customstyleone}{
    numbers=\showLineNo,
    numbersep=5pt
}
\lstset{style=customstyleone}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=python code example]
    def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

but work as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{customstyleone}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt
}
\lstset{style=customstyleone}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=python code example]
    def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

How can I use custom command pass to lstdefinestyle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listings` package uses a mechanism which doesn't expand the value of the `numbers` key to search for the valid values (while the error recovery does expand the value). Hence your usage with a macro holding the value for `numbers` doesn't work like that.

We could however define an alternative key (if it doesn't exist yet) which expands its value and passes it to the `numbers` key. You could consider the following a small hack, as we play with `listings` `keyval`-namespace (or an extension?).

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{listings}

\def\showLineNo{none}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KV@lst@numbers-expanded}
  {%
    \define@key{lst}{numbers-expanded}
      {\expandafter\KV@lst@numbers\expanded{{#1}}}%
  }
  {\GenericError{}{key numbers-expanded already defined}{}}
\makeatother
\lstdefinestyle{customstyleone}{
    numbers-expanded=\showLineNo,
    numbersep=5pt
}
\lstset{style=customstyleone}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=python code example]
    def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's works. Thanks very much, Skillmon.