# How to get lstdefinestyle to accept a custom command with an argument?

Tags: listings, verbatim, matlab-prettifier

I want to customize the style of `Matlab-editor` in `matlab-prettifier` package. What I want is to produce background for MATLAB styled commands, but it does not seem that `basicstyle` key accepts commands with arguments

It is possible to get this by creating custom commands such as in

[Different background colors for lstinline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51038/different-background-colors-for-lstinline)

However, I would rather use `\lstinline` command directly because I want TeXstudio to highlight verbatim code. This topic seems to contain what I want, but I need to adapt it for my specific needs

[listings lstdefinestyle not work with custom defined command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642321/listings-lstdefinestyle-not-work-with-custom-defined-command)

This is the result I want

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage[]{matlab-prettifier}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{matlab-inline}{
    % style
    style=Matlab-editor, % default style for matlab pretification
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\color{DodgerBlue3}, % font style and size
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\matlabinline}[1]
{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \node[fill=Ivory1, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,  inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=1pt, opacity=0.75, anchor=base] (node) {\bigstrut#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=frame, allowframebreaks=0.99]
    
    \smash{\rlap{\vrule width 0.1pt depth 0em height 0.75em}}%
    \smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
    \matlabinline{\lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|plot(X1, Y1, LineSpec1)|} \lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|plot(X1, Y1, LineSpec1)|
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you want the second inline `\lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|plot(X1, Y1, LineSpec1)|
` to have the identical result as the first line `\matlabinline{\lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|plot(X1, Y1, LineSpec1)|}
`?

Comment: This is what I really want

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there's no way to solve this without patching `lstinline`. It isn't really recommended to patch it, for your specific problem I think the alternative solution (changing syntax highlighting in TeXStudio) works as well -- see
[Making TeXstudio syntax highlighting recognize a custom verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616051/250119)
, but if you insist there is this way:

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage[]{matlab-prettifier}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{matlab-inline}{
    % style
    style=Matlab-editor, % default style for matlab pretification
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\color{DodgerBlue3}, % font style and size
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{tikz}

\NewCommandCopy \oldlstinline \lstinline

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand \lstinline {o v} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \node[fill=Ivory1, inner~sep=0mm, outer~sep=0mm,  inner~xsep=0mm, inner~ysep=1pt, opacity=0.75, anchor=base]
            (node) {\bigstrut \oldlstinline[#1]{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fastrecompileendpreamble
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=frame, allowframebreaks=0.99]
    
    \smash{\rlap{\vrule width 0.1pt depth 0em height 0.75em}}%
    \smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%

    \lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|plot(X1, Y1, LineSpec1)|
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It redefines `lstinline` the way described in the code.